# Python - Convert multiple lists to multiple dictionaries using one of lists as dict names

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

Working on a small python project and have reached a point that has got me stumped.

```
runners = ["Tom","Bob","Bill","Gary"]

runner_id = [123223,234345,356543,487334]

event_id = [11,12,13,14]

event_time = [12.30,13.00,14.00,16.00]
```

I have the data above and want to end up with a dictionary for each runner, with the dict named as the runners name.

So result would be as follows:

```
Tom = {runner_id : 123223, event_id : 11, event_time : 12.30}

Bob = {runner_id : 234345, event_id : 12, event_time : 13.00}

Bill = {runner_id : 356543, event_id : 13, event_time : 14.00}

Gary = {runner_id : 487334, event_id : 14, event_time : 16.00}
```

Stumped as to how to actually have the dict named as I need it to, ie as the names from one of the original lists.

Have read an awful lot of posts but can't find an answer to this specific question.

All helpful pointers in the right direction gratefully received.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dict comprehension and `zip` function :

```
runners = ["Tom","Bob","Bill","Gary"]
runner_id = [123223,234345,356543,487334]
event_id = [11,12,13,14]
event_time = [12.30,13.00,14.00,16.00]

print {name:{'runner_id' : i, 'event_id' : j, 'event_time' : k} for i,j,k,name in zip(runner_id,event_id,event_time,runners)}
```

result :

```
{'Bob': {'event_id': 12, 'event_time': 13.0, 'runner_id': 234345}, 'Bill': {'event_id': 13, 'event_time': 14.0, 'runner_id': 356543}, 'Gary': {'event_id': 14, 'event_time': 16.0, 'runner_id': 487334}, 'Tom': {'event_id': 11, 'event_time': 12.3, 'runner_id': 123223}}
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the runner names as keys to a larger dictionary

```
runner_dict = {}
for index, runner in enumerate(runners):
    runner_dict[runner] = {
        'runner_id'  : runner_id[index],
        'event_id'   : event_id[index],
        'event_time' : event_time[index]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot better if you instead have one dictionary containing all the runners and their dictionaries. So instead you have this:

```
runners = {
    "Tom" : {runner_id : 123223, event_id : 11, event_time : 12.30},
    "Bob" : {runner_id : 234345, event_id : 12, event_time : 13.00},
    "Bill" : {runner_id : 356543, event_id : 13, event_time : 14.00},
    "Gary" : {runner_id : 487334, event_id : 14, event_time : 16.00},
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As follow

```
runners = ["Tom","Bob","Bill","Gary"]
runner_id = [123223,234345,356543,487334]
event_id = [11,12,13,14]
event_time = [12.30,13.00,14.00,16.00]

runners_dict = {}
for index, runner in enumerate(runners):
    runners_dict[runner] = {
        'runner_id' : runner_id[index],
        'event_id' : event_id[index],
        'event_time' : event_time[index]
    }
```

And if you want to get certain runner dict then

```
runners_dict['name']
```

Comment: Awesome - many thanks, had been going round in circles with 'enumerate' :-)